# how to run a perl script in fedora system in an hourly basis. I have a perl script which will check the port in an IP is open or not

Tags: linux, perl, cron

I have a perl script which will check the port in an IP is open or not.I want this script will run hourly basis in linux system.Please advise. The code is given below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dsn = 'dbi:mysql:dbname:localhost:3306';
                my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:dbname:localhost:3306',"root7","pass");
                if(!$dbh)
                {                    
                    print "Not Connnected";
                }
                else
                {
                    print "Connnected";

                my @temp;
                my $tmp=time();
                my @timeData = localtime(time);
                $temp[0] = $timeData[2].":".$timeData[1].":".$timeData[0];
                $temp[1] = $timeData[3]."-".($timeData[4]+1)."-".($timeData[5]+1900);

                my $filename = 'log_c.txt';
                open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
                print $fh "date:$temp[1]: Time:$temp[0]\n";
                close $fh;
                #print "done\n"

                undef @timeData;
                undef $tmp;
                undef @temp;

                }
```

Comment: Use cron https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cron

Comment: How to use cronjobs in fedora 12

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way around doing some own research, including some reading of some fine manuals.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [cron](http://man.cx/cron) is for.

You create a cronjob using the command `crontab -e`. A cron job is a specification on how often to run a particular job, and either the command or shell script to run.

For example, to run your Perl script once per hour:

```
0 * * * * /usr/home/foo/perscript.pl
```

The first five columns are a time specification (See crontab man page Section 5: `man crontab -s5`). However, cron depends upon a `daemon` that launches the crontab task every minute to check the various crontab tables (because each user can have one) to see if there any tasks to run. There's also a permission scheme where some people are *allowed* and others are *denied* to run cron jobs.

It's a bit much to go through the entire crontab setup in an answer -- especially since there are minor variations between various systems. However, now that you know about crontab, you can Google [the information you need](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=crontab%20setup).

Comment: That is not right. A cron job having such specification * 0-24 * * * will run every minute, not hourly.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use cron (the system's build in feature for scheduling things ) or include the

```
use Proc::Daemon;
```

library to set your script working as a daemon

and by specifying

```
Proc::Daemon::Init;
```

you enable this daemon feature of the script. Access control thought it might be a bit tedious so I suggest you add a control script to your new 'service' as follows:

( I repeat that the cron approach comes more in handy with this way you will have your own service running  )

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Simple YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE init.d script conceived to work on Linux systems
# as it does use of the /proc filesystem.


EXEC=/path/to/script/
PIDFILE=/var/run/script.pid


case "$1" in
    start)
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
        then
                echo "$PIDFILE exists, process is already running or crashed"
        else
                echo "Starting YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE server..."
                $EXEC
                PID=$(pgrep blacklist)
                echo ${PID} > /var/run/blacklist.pid
                # $CONF
        fi
        ;;
    status)
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
        then
                PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
                echo "Service YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE running with pid ${PID} "
        else
                echo "Service is stopped"
        fi
        ;;
    restart)
        echo -n "Restarting blacklist: "
        if [ ! -f $PIDFILE ]
        then
                echo "$PIDFILE does not exist, process is not running"
        else
                PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
                echo "Stopping ..."
                kill -9 ${PID}
                while [ -x /proc/${PID} ]
                do
                    echo "Waiting for YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE to shutdown ..."
                    sleep 1
                done
                rm -rf /var/run/blacklist.pid
                echo "YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE stopped"
        fi
                if [ -f $PIDFILE ]
        then
                echo "$PIDFILE exists, process is already running or crashed"
        else
                echo "Starting YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE server..."
                $EXEC
                PID=$(pgrep blacklist)
                echo ${PID} > $PIDFILE
                # $CONF
        fi

        ;;    
    stop)
        if [ ! -f $PIDFILE ]
        then
                echo "$PIDFILE does not exist, process is not running"
        else
                PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
                echo "Stopping ..."
                kill -9 ${PID}
                while [ -x /proc/${PID} ]
                do
                    echo "Waiting for YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE to shutdown ..."
                    sleep 1
                done
                rm -rf $PIDFILE
                echo "YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE stopped"
        fi
        ;;
    *)
         echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You should request permission to create a cron job or let to create this job by administrator.
The cron job, that runs hourly, has following specification:

```
3 * * * * absolute_path/your_program_name  optional_parameters  optional_redirections
```

In the example the cron job will be started hourly at 3rd minute.
If a machine has many cron jobs, I recommend you to avoid start of cron job at minutes 0th, or 30th because of expected overloading. In practice most of people haven't heard about another number of minutes.